# check if an element exists in queue of array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, queue

I have a queue of arrays in Java. What is the easiest way to check if the array already exists in the queue?

```
Queue<Integer[]> q = new LinkedList<>();
if(!q.contains(new Integer[]{r,c})) {
    q.add(new Integer[]{r, c});
}
```

I know what I am checking for is an object and even if an array with same values as r and c already exists in the queue, it will be considered as a different object and returns false.

Brute force way is to convert the array to string using `Arrays.toString(arr)` and loop through the queue and check if the value exists.

I am looking for any other efficient way to do the same.

Comment: You will have to loop through the queue and use Arrays.equals.  There's no reason to use `toString`.

Comment: what do you mean under "efficient"? is packing two integers into long efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is write a wrapper for your object.  I am using a `record` here but a regular class would work as well.  The record needs to override `equals` to use `Arrays.equals()` for the comparison.  I also overrode `toString` to display the array when the object is printed.

```
record MyInt(int[] val) {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
         return Arrays.hashCode(val);
    }   
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object ob) {
        if (!(ob instanceof MyInt)) {
            return false;
        }
        MyInt myOb = (MyInt)ob;
        return Arrays.equals(val, myOb.val);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(val);
    }
}
```

Define the queue and some data

```
Queue<MyInt> queue =
        new LinkedList<>();

List<MyInt> data = List.of(
        new MyInt(new int[] {1,2}),
        new MyInt(new int[] {2,3}),
        new MyInt(new int[] {3,4}),
        new MyInt(new int[] {4,5}),
        new MyInt(new int[] {1,2}),
        new MyInt(new int[] {2,3}),
        new MyInt(new int[] {3,4}),
        new MyInt(new int[] {5,6}));
```

Add the data as in your question.

```
for (MyInt mi : data) {
    if(!queue.contains(mi)) {
        queue.add(mi);
    }
}
                
queue.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 5]
[5, 6]
```

A more efficient solution (as the values are hashed) would be to use a set which also by its nature doesn't permit duplicates.  The down side is that sets don't allow random access of their values.

```
Set<MyInt> set =  new HashSet<>();

for (MyInt mi : data) {
    set.add(mi);
}
                
set.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 5]
[5, 6]
```

For the above to work, both `equals()` and `hashCode()` must be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a queue of Integer[], you should create a subclass and use that for your queue.

```
public class MyInts {
  public int[] myInts;
  public int[] getInts() {
    return myInts;
  }
  public boolean equals(MyInts ints) {
    if (!myInts.length == ints.myInts.length) return false;
    int i = 0;
    while (myInts[i] == ints.myInts[i] && i < myInts.length) {
      i++;
    }
    return i == myInts.length;
  }
}
```